# Visual Basic - Abrir un archivo Excel

Tags: vb.net

Quiero manipular un archivo **Excel** con **Visual Basic**, usando **Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library** para ello tengo:

```vb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Public Aplicacion As New Excel.Application
    Public Libro As New Excel.Workbook
    Public Hoja As New Excel.Worksheet


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Libro = Aplicacion.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")
        Hoja = Aplicacion.Worksheets("Hoja1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Pero la respuesta es una excepcion:

> Error al crear el formulario. Consulte Exception.InnerException para obtener más detalles. Error: No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Tengo instalado **Office 2016**

¿De qué forma puedo solucionar el error?

### En Respuesta a Cristina

Es proyecto de Windows Forms. En cuanto a asignar permisos, no entiendo a qué te refieres, y configurar usuario en DCOM.

Dime cómo puedo realizar lo que mencionas.

Comment: Es aplicación web o windows???, tienes que asignar permisos en carpetas temporales que usa Excel y también configurar el usuario en DCOM

Comment: Editado........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Encontré la respuesta**, he aquí les dejo completo el código :)

En el código se usa un botón para abrir el archivo.

Al finalizar las acciones se cierra la aplicación.

```vb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Aplicacion As Excel.Application
        Dim Libro As Excel.Workbook
        Dim Hoja As Excel.Worksheet

        Aplicacion = New Excel.Application
        Libro = Aplicacion.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xlsx")
        Hoja = Libro.Worksheets("SEMANA1")

        'Aquí manipulen su archivo
        'Aquí manipulen su archivo
        'Aquí manipulen su archivo

        Libro.Close()
        Aplicacion.Quit()

        releaseObject(Aplicacion)
        releaseObject(Libro)
        releaseObject(Hoja)

    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Funciona a la perfección gracias, un aporte en caso de requerir guardar el archivo **sobreescribiendo la información**:

```
Libro.save()
Libro.Close()
Aplicacion.Quit()

releaseObject(Aplicacion)
releaseObject(Libro)
releaseObject(Hoja)
```